# Generate RDLC through c# code

Tags: c#-3.0, dynamic-rdlc-generation

Is there any method to generate the rdlc file programatically? I tried looking on MS sample but it is only for rdl file.

Thanks

Comment: read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56919464/5848472) post. It should help you to get new idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/microsoftreporting.aspx) on this a few years ago over on code project.    It's been a while, and it was written for SSRS 2005 in .Net 2.0, but hopefully it will point you in the right direction.