# How to Create From ReportViewer in C# by using coded DataSet

Tags: c#, report, reportviewer

I want to create an somehow, invoice like report on C# ReportViewer. But I don't know how to format the report by code. I'm getting an error on my code. Here is what I use:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PrototypeV9;Integrated Security=True";
            conn.Open();

            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("HEY");
            }


            this.reportViewer1.Reset();
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"C:\Users\Lenon\Documents\Euge's Folder\SampReport\SampReport\bin\Report2.rdlc";
            ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("dsNewDataSet_Table", getData());
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
            //this.reportViewer1.DataBind();
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();

            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {

            MessageBox.Show("no");
        }
    }

    private void rptGetDataset()
    {
        string path = @"C:\Program Files";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.DataSetName = "dsNewDataSet";
        string sql = "";
        sql = "select * from Sample3 where ProductID = 'ITM42512'";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
        ds.GetXmlSchema();
        da.Fill(ds);
        ds.WriteXmlSchema(path + @"\App_Code\Ds.xsd");
        ds.WriteXml(path + @"\App_Code\Ds.xml");
    }

     private DataTable getData()
{
    DataSet dss = new DataSet();
    string sql = "";
    sql = "select * from Sample3 where ProductID = 'ITM42512'";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
    da.Fill(dss);
    DataTable dt = dss.Tables[0];
    return dt;
}
```

How can I solve my problem? Or is there other way to create an invoice with ReportViewer. Thanks!

Comment: Could you be more specific about "an error"?

Comment: "an error occured during local report processing. the report definition for report "<the report path>" has not been specified"

Answer (score 2):

Being this an old question, you might already have an answer, but I've been working on something similar and experienced what seems to be the same situation (which is what lead me here).

That error is being triggered because a RDLC file is missing. You can create the RDLC definition statically or dynamically.

For the static version, you can easily find many tutorials on how to do it using Visual Studio's wizard. If you want to do it dynamically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521959/generate-rdlc-through-c-sharp-code) leads to a tutorial in Code Project designed for SSRS 2005 in .Net 2.0. It's quite good and detailed.

A different solution (which is what I used) is in [got reportviewer?](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/), look for "Generate RDLC dynamically - Table". The sample code will help you create your own version; it doesn't require many changes to get it working in your project.

The dynamic version is particularly helpful if you're dealing with a large number of reports.

Hope this helps, cheers!