# Is there a way to fix this error "cannot create a data reader for dataset 'Dataset1'

Tags: c#

I am printing reports using Report Viewer. I followed a tutorial about 
    this code but I got this error "Cannot create a data reader for dataset 'Dataset1'.

I am using reportviewer and rdlc in this.
I dont know if the problem is the the Reportdatasource itself or the dataset:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Water_Quality_Monitoring
{
    public partial class FishpondForm : Form
    {

        Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource rs = new 
Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource();
        private DataGridView grid;

        public FishpondForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Print> list = new List<Print>();
            list.Clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < agriInfo.dataAgriInfo.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                list.Add(new Print
                {
                  MemberID = 
                  agriInfo.dataAgriInfo.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(),
                  LastName = 
                  agriInfo.dataAgriInfo.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(),
                  FirstName = 
                  agriInfo.dataAgriInfo.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(),
                  MiddleName = 
                  agriInfo.dataAgriInfo.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(),
                  Contact = 
                  agriInfo.dataAgriInfo.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(),
                  Status = 
                  agriInfo.dataAgriInfo.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString()
                });
                Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource rs = new 
                Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource();
                rs.Name = "Dataset1";
                rs.Value = list;
                PrintFishpond frm = new PrintFishpond();
                frm.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                frm.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rs);
                frm.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = 
                "Water_Quality_Monitoring.Report1.rdlc";
                frm.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Print
    {
        public string MemberID { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string Contact { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I expect to print what is in the datagrid dataAgriInfo. I hope you can help me.

Comment: The error is. "Cannot create a data reader for dataset 'Dataset1'

Comment: It looks like the ReportDataSource.Value property is expecting a DataTable, not a list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.rdlc Report - Cannot create a data reader for dataset 'DataSet1'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365731/rdlc-report-cannot-create-a-data-reader-for-dataset-dataset1)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the list into a datatable and assigning the datatable to the value property of the ReportDataSource.  Use the function cut+paste from this post: [How to convert a list into data table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100783/how-to-convert-a-list-into-data-table)

Then...

```
rs.Value = table;
```

Comment: cant access the ObjectReader

Comment: I don't have VS in front of me on this computer so can't test but, I posted a link to a similar SO post that has a function you can  cut+paste and call to convert your List<T> to a datatable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a data table out of the datagrid and then assign it to the report data source as given below:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = ((DataView)dataAgriInfo.ItemsSource).ToTable(); 
dt.TableName = "TableNameYouWantToSet" 

Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource rs = new 
                Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource(dt.TableName, dt);  


frm.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
frm.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rs);
frm.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```